# Can I use a .cer file obtained from Apple Developer/Xcode to codesign a Windows application?

Tags: windows, macos, certificate, codesign

I have a .cer file obtained through Xcode and apple developer site that I use to codesign my application on OSX.  Is it possible to codesign the Windows version of the app with the same .cer file?

Comment: Sorry man, I have never attempted codesigning applications before.  Maybe you could offer a slightly more helpful explanation of why I am doing something stupid.  As far as I can tell it often costs as much $178 a year for most Windows codesigning certificates, if possible I would rather not pay this.

Comment: Oh, I was just wondering why. What happens when you try to sign a Windows app with the .cer file? Does it cause any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that from the age of the post this will no be relevant anymore for Mike, but someone else might be trying to do the same. So here is how:

All you need to do is to export the certificate and its key as pkcs12 from the Keychain in your Mac Dev box (using extension .pfx) and use it with signtool.exe on your windows box.

If you have problems doing this, you can export the key and cert to PEM format, and execute the following command to create the windows signing pfx.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out sign_cert.pfx -inkey your_key.key -in your_cert.pem -certfile your_intermediate_chain.pem
```